# URLs of type "http://user:password@example.com" in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I had a web page in which the user specify an username and a password to make queries to a third site. In Firefox and Chrome I can make an URL of the form `http://user:password@example.com`, but Internet Explorer 7 says that it can not find the address.

Is there any form of setting user and password in the URL for Internet Explorer 7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any form of setting user and password in the URL for Internet Explorer 7?

No. This was disabled for security reasons: It was misused by phishers to obfuscate the real site address.

Reference:

- [Internet Explorer does not support user names and passwords in Web site addresses (MSDN)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489)

Answer (score 4):

You are correct: IE 7 does not support user names and passwords in HTTP or HTTPS URLs.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489

The following workaround is given:

> To disable the new default behavior in
>   Windows Explorer and Internet
>   Explorer, create iexplore.exe and
>   explorer.exe DWORD values in one of
>   the following registry keys and set
>   their value data to 0.
>
> For all users of the program, set the
>   value in the following registry key:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
>
> For the current user of the program
>   only, set the value in the following
>   registry key:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE

Comment: With at least IE11 on Windows 2012, enabling these registry settings and using the user:pass@ syntax can trigger non-standard behaviour. For example after clicking a link the URL may have (null) at some point within it when it normally works fine, AJAX requests may fail because they aren't sending the basic authentication header, links with target attributes may open in the wrong places etc. If you're automating the browser (with say Selenium) and you need to do basic auth with IE try using an intercepting web proxy that can add headers instead.

Comment: I suppose that is useful information, but I'm not sure why you would be using an IE 7 workaround on IE 11.

Comment: For some reason people using Selenium gravitate towards it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23519791/4985326

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess with the registry yourself or are finding it difficult/still having trouble, Microsoft's got something called "microsoft fixit" .. seems a little gimmicky but it worked for me.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489#FixItForMeAlways

EDIT: Upon inspection the fixit installer also added a local key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN - iexplore.exe DWORD 1

and

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_LOCALMACHINE_LOCKDOWN\Settings - LOCALMACHINE_CD_UNLOCK DWORD 0

hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for "username password url internet explorer" turns up [this Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/834489), which mentions the issue and describes workarounds.