# Basic authentication with Selenium in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: selenium, protractor, internet-explorer-11, basic-authentication

I read [Basic authentication with Selenium in Internet Explorer 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498710/basic-authentication-with-selenium-in-internet-explorer-10/23519791#23519791)
And I change my register key and when I use the user and pass in the url I don't see the basic authentication popup, but actually the page is not load. I see blank page!

I see my url in the IE but nothing happened - I see white page.
Must I change somethin in IE too?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without some workarounds.

I also needed the same feature and previous SO answer confirms, that is it either impossible or possible with high probability of failure.

One thing I learned about Protrator is not to try to make too complicated stuff with it, or I'll have a bad time.

As for the feature-  I ended up making Protractor to initiate Node.js task, which  use **request** to make the authentication and provide back the data.

Taken straight from **request** module:

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth('username', 'password', false);
        // or 
        request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
            'auth': {
                'user': 'username',
                'pass': 'password',
                'sendImmediately': false
            }
        });
        // or 
        request.get('http://some.server.com/').auth(null, null, true, 'bearerToken');
        // or 
        request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
            'auth': {
                'bearer': 'bearerToken'
            }
        });
```

Comment: Hi Dejan thank you very much for your advice. But I really can not imagine how the node.js task will open the url and login and then the protractor "it" tests will continue...