# Handling authorize popup window

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, alert

I'm using Selenium and webDriver and C#. I want to write some code to access a webpage automatically. And there will popup an authorize window (two input control, ex.user should press "admin" and password "admin", then click button "OK").

My code is:

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Sendkeys("admin");
alert.Sendkeys("\t");     // it not works. FAILED!
alert.Sendkeys("admin");
alert.Accept();`
```

My Question is how can I enter name/password into the popup window correctly?
How Selenium handle the popup window like these?

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: It is a Window pop up or javascript pop up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver and Basic Auth in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572956/selenium-webdriver-and-basic-auth-in-ie)  also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672407/basic-authentication-in-selenium-2-set-up-for-firefoxdriver-chromedriver-and    and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304752/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: It is a Window pop up I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Http Basic auth window:

[image]

Try change URL to: http://user:password@www.yourserveradress.com