# python selenium windows authentication in internet explorer

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have issues to get through the windows authentication when creating an automation test (Python) with Selenium Webdriver using the InternetExplorer Driver

When using Chrome it works to access https//username:password@site.com but not with Internet Explorer 11

I saw the solution of changing values in the registry, but due to admin rights restrictions that can not be implemented.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import datetime
import win32com.client


driver=webdriver.Ie('IEDriverServer.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")   
shell.Sendkeys("admin",TAB, )  
time.sleep(1)
shell.Sendkeys("{TAB}")
time.sleep(1)
shell.Sendkeys("admin") 
time.sleep(1)
shell.Sendkeys("{ENTER}")
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: how about disabling Basic Authentication in your test environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate. check the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105623/urls-of-type-http-userpasswordexample-com-in-internet-explorer/4105642#4105642

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate as the link suggests to change the registry settings or read cookies which is not a possible solution in my case.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg Actully we do not have a test environment for our site and we are writing a automation script on a client website the above provided URL is just an example and not the actual site but the behaviour is same.